# Decode string with hidden control characters

Tags: python

I have a file containing lines with hidden control characters. An example line looks like this:

```
go!^Mbap^[<80>
```

The `^M`, `^[`, and `<80>` are hidden characters. When I print the line I do not see these characters. However, if I use the `repr()` function I can see these character represented by things like, `\x1b0`.

How can I change these characters into a unicode character of my choosing?

I've tried to use the string modules `translate()` function and also regular expressions, but I can't seem to convert these hidden characters.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `str.translate` and (below) `unicode.translate`:

```
In [48]: import string

In [49]: text = 'go!\x1b0'

In [50]: text.translate(string.maketrans('\x1b\xa0','??'))
Out[50]: 'go!?0'
```

The above command translates all `'\x1b'` and `'\xa0'` to question marks.

---

Or, if you want to translate a unicode string:

```
In [55]: text = 'go!\x1b0'

In [56]: unitext = text.decode('latin-1')

In [57]: unitext
Out[57]: u'go!\x1b0'

In [58]: unitext.translate({ord(u'\x1b'):ord(u'?')})
Out[58]: u'go!?0'
```

If you have more than one character to translate, it may be more convenient to define the table this way:

```
In [59]: table = dict(zip(map(ord, u'\xb1\xa0'), map(ord, u'??')))

In [60]: unitext.translate(table)
Out[60]: u'go!\x1b0'
```